# Notationquestion: Matrices

Tags: linear-algebra

I have to determine the base change matrix $S=M(id,A,B)$.

Now i looked at how to do it, but which base is right and which left in doing it?

i would write A|B and then try to get the elementary matrix at the right

but is A->B or B->A wanted here?

Comment: It is `A -> B`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The standard notation of the base matricx $B$ to $A$ ($B\dashrightarrow A$) is $S=M(id,A,B)$.

Comment: is there any reason why it is notated that way? seems confusing to me, but thanks nontheless.

Comment: by definition $M(id,B,A)$  is the matrix whose colons are vectors
of $B$ expressed in the base $ A$ and  denoted by $P$ this
[notation $P$ is standard to designed  the change base matrix from
old base $ A$ to the new base $B$], and you can remember this easy
by the formula $M(f,B)=M(id,A,B)M(f,A)M(id,B,A)$ or
$M(f,B)=P^{-1}M(f,A)P$
 where $M(f,B)$ is the matrix of the endomorphism $f$ in the new base $B$ and
 $M(f,A)$  the matrix of $f$ in the old base $A$.

Comment: So just to be clear: i have calculated a matrix C, where $A*C=B$, would this then be M(id,B,A) ?

Comment: please can you precise the notation confusion bettween matrix and bases, I not understand your question

Comment: oh sorry, A,B are bases, and $A*C=B$, is C then M(id,B,A)? My confusion only came from "i go from A to B" so in my mind a notation in the form of M(id,A,B) would make more sense. but ok, thats definitionstuff i have to learn i guess.